# How to force Total Column to appear at last in a TRANSFORM SQL statement

Tags: sql, ms-access, pivot, transform

I have the following SQL statement to create a summary view

```
TRANSFORM Sum(Amount) AS CurrAmount 
SELECT Currency, Sum(Amount) AS TotalAmount 
From MyTable 
GROUP BY Currency
ORDER BY Currency 
PIVOT Source
```

It creates the following view

```
Currency    TotalAmount Retail  Corporate     Others
EUR               7,071    585      2,345      4,141
GBP              10,444  2,322      4,889      3,233
JPY               7,050  1,295      4,500      1,255
USD               1,625    250        450        925
```

I am looking for help wherein I need the 'TotalAmount' field to appear as the last column. Much appreciated

Niz

Comment: In datasheet view, you can drag&drop `TotalAmount` to the position you want it, and save the query. It will stay there, if you reopen the query, but not if the query structure changes. So this is only a workaround, but it may help.

Comment: Thanks Andre. This definitely is the option in MSAccess. I missed to mention though that my requirement is to use the SQL in my application and in there, I am unable to move it.

Comment: Any help here friends?

Comment: It may be impossible. But let's see... Oh, what is *your application*?

Answer (score 1):

I think your requirement for column ordering/sequence can be handled by the `IN` clause that is supported by the `TRANSFORM` operator.  Have a look at this:

```
TRANSFORM <aggregate-function-expression>
    <select-statement>
PIVOT <expression>
[IN (<column-value-list>)]
```

where `<aggregate-function-expression>` is an expression created with one of the aggregate functions, `<select-statement>` contains a `GROUP BY` clause, and `<column-value-list>` is a list of required values expected to be returned by the `PIVOT` expression, enclosed in quotes and separated by commas. (You can use the `IN` clause to force the output sequence of the columns.)

In other words, just use `IN` and put your quote/comma delimited list of columns in the desired order (e.g. `IN ("Currency", "Retail", "Corporate", "Others", "TotalAmount")`)

Seems a little complicated to me, but it appears to be supported by Access.

Note: this info was grabbed from the following article:
[TRANSFORM Statement](http://sourcedaddy.com/ms-access/transform-statement.html)

Comment: Ah, of course. I have used the (somewhat similar) IN clause for pivot queries in T-SQL, but totally forgotten that Access has this too. Thanks!  (Note: I have to wait until the bounty is 24h old to award it.)

Comment: It somewhat does the job but behaves quite strange at times. Moreover, the departments (retail, corporate) are not fixed for me. New departments keep coming and therefore I cannot be hard coding it every time. I had it resolved in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

The solution using IN clause somewhat does the job but behaves quite strange at times. Moreover, the departments (retail, corporate) are not fixed for me. New departments keep coming and therefore I cannot be hard coding it every time. I had it resolved in a simpler way.

```
SELECT Currency,
(SELECT SUM(t1.Amount) FROM MyTable t1 WHERE t1.Source = 'Retail' AND t1.Curr = pos.Curr) Retail,
(SELECT SUM(t1.Amount) FROM MyTable t1 WHERE t1.Source = 'Corporate' AND t1.Curr = pos.Curr) Corporate,
(SELECT SUM(t1.Amount) FROM MyTable t1 WHERE t1.Source NOT IN ('Retail','Corporate') AND t1.Curr = pos.Curr) Others,
(SELECT SUM(t1.Amount) FROM MyTable t1 WHERE t1.Curr = pos.Curr) Total
FROM MyTable pos
GROUP BY Curr
ORDER BY Curr
```

Even in the above, if there are new departments (appearing in Others) I will end up changing the SQL if I may need to specify, but still is in my control unlike the TRANSFORM statement where is goes out of control.

Thanks guys.